# Angular 2 RC-5 Async testing is not working

Tags: angular, angular2-testing

That's the code:

```
import {
  async,
  inject,
  TestBed
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  Http,
  Response,
  ResponseOptions,
  RequestOptions,
  BaseRequestOptions,
  ConnectionBackend
} from "@angular/http";
import {MockBackend, MockConnection} from "@angular/http/testing";
import {HttpInterceptor, RequestWrapped} from "./http.interceptor.service.ts";

describe("Http interceptor", () => {
  beforeEach(() =>{
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        {provide: ConnectionBackend, useClass: MockBackend},
        {provide: RequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions},
        Http
      ],
    });
  });

  it('should get blogs', inject([Http, MockBackend], (http:Http, backend:MockBackend) => {
    let connection:MockConnection;
    backend.connections.subscribe(connection =>
      connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions('awesome')))
    );
    http.request('data.json').subscribe((res) => {
      expect(res.text()).toBe('awesome2');
    });
  }));
});
```

This test should fail, obviouly awesome is not equal awesome2, why is not working?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm having a similar problem. Had already tried using async as per @peeskillet's suggestion but that doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Wrapp the whole test case with `async()` function. See docs of angular testing async function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `it` method finishes executing before the async callback. In vanilla Jasmine you would handle asynchrony with `done`

```
it('', function (done) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    expect(2).toBe(2);
    done();
  }, 1000);
});
```

The `done` is how Jasmine knows we're finished with all the asynchronous events and the test is complete.

With Angular, instead of explicitly calling `done`, we should the fundtion in `async`. This will wrap the entire method in a zone, where it keeps track of all async calls. when all the async calls are done, then the test completes. This is different from a *synchronous* test where once the method completes, the test is complete

```
import { async } from '@angular/core/testing';                

                    // async wapper
it('should get blogs', async(inject([Http, MockBackend], (http:Http, backend:MockBackend) => {
  let connection:MockConnection;
  backend.connections.subscribe(connection =>
    connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions('awesome')))
  );
  http.request('data.json').subscribe((res) => {
    expect(res.text()).toBe('awesome2');
  });
})));
```

There is also `fakeAsync`, that allows you to control the "ticks"

```
it('should get blogs', fakeAsync(inject([Http, MockBackend], (http:Http, backend:MockBackend) => {
  let connection:MockConnection;
  backend.connections.subscribe(connection =>
    connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions('awesome')))
  );
  let text;
  http.request('data.json').subscribe((res) => {
    text = res.text();
  });
  tick();
  expect(res.text()).toBe('awesome2');
})));
```